# TornadoFX - Problem displaying a modal view with 'openWindow'

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

When I show a view with `openWindow` and the `Modality.WINDOW_MODAL` modifier, the first time this window behaves like a modal window, but if I close the view and open it again, it behaves like a non-modal view (access to the parent view is possible).

What could this behavior be due to?

Thanks very much.

```
class VentanaPrincipal: View("Ventana principal") {

    private val openModalSinParametros: OpenModalSinParametros by inject()

    override val root = vbox {
        // Posicionar vista principal.
        primaryStage.x = 10.0
        primaryStage.y = 10.0
        setPrefSize(400.0, 400.0)
        alignment = Pos.CENTER
        label {
            font = Font(14.0)
            textFill = Color.NAVY
            text = "ESTA ES LA VENTANA PRINCIPAL"
        }
        button {
            text = "Abrir ventana con 'openWindow' sin parámetros"
            action {
                openWindowSinParametros.openWindow(modality = Modality.WINDOW_MODAL)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either pass `modality: Modality = Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL`, or simply call `openWindowSinParametros.openModal()` to get the proper defaults :)

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much for the reply. I already knew that doing it as you point out, it works correctly. My doubt was regarding the operation of the Modality.WINDOW_MODAL parameter, which the first time makes the window modal and the following doesn't, and it seemed a behavior a littel bit strange. Maybe the second time the view is called, the owner becomes null?